# Bind ComboBox WPF custom object

Tags: wpf, combobox, bind, two-way

I've been wracking my brain for the past several hours with a problem that probably is quite easy to solve. I hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

I have a WPF project where the user can edit an xml file. I serialize the xml file to an object called `FilterSetting` that has the following properties:

```
    public int FilterType {get; set;}
    public string FilterName {get; set;} 
    public string FilterDescription {get; set;}
```

I have two textboxes and a combobox generated from a static dictionary with the following values

```
    Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
       d.Add(1, "FilterType 1 description");
       d.Add(2, "FilterType 2 description");
       d.Add(3, "FilterType 3 description");
       d.Add(4, "FilterType 4 description");
       d.Add(5, "FilterType 5 description");
       d.Add(6, "FilterType 6 description");
```

I set the datacontext to the `FilterSetting` object and do a two-way bind on the textboxes to `FilterName` And `FilterDescription` which works great. What I'd like to do is bind the ComboBox the same way using the options from my dictionary and do a two-way bind to the `FilterType` property on my `FilterSetting` object.

How do I do that? :)

Peter

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to do. You have an object that encompasses FilterType, FilterName, and FilterDescription. These sound like items that all go together. Next, you have a UI that has Textboxes for name and description, and a combobox that has a dictionary representing FilterType-> FilterDescription? If you make a two way binding for the combobox, are you planning to modify the values of the ENTIRE setting object (type, name, & desc)? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the relationships between the filter properties :). I don't want to misinterpret before I answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, it seems that you want the combobox to display the descriptions while binding to the FilterType.
If that is the case, use the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath to accomplish this.
eg in the xml:

```
<ComboBox ...
DisplayMemberPath = "FilterDescription"
SelectedValuePath = "FilterType"
.../>
```

Comment: His ItemsSource is the dictionary, so he’s going to want Key for SelectedValuePath and Value for DisplayMemberPath

Comment: Hi Andrew and Ed. I want the combobox to display the descriptions from my dictionary and it does this if I use Key for SelectedValuePath and Value for DisplayMemberPath. But when I load FilterSetting object the combobox value isn't automatically set and changes aren't saved like with the textboxes. I need to somehow link the FilterSetting object to the combobox.

Comment: Have you set SelectedValue="{Binding FilterSetting.FilterType}" ?